# Please help with applications folder

Tags: permissions, chmod, elementary-os

I wanted to have full permissions on my `applications` folder, but I used `chmod` incorrectly, and accidentally made the `application` folder only accessible to root. I don’t have read or write privileges to any apps or anything in that folder, so I can't open new apps, the only apps I have open that I can use are Firefox and discord. The only apps I can open are: camera, calculator, desktopius, document viewer, screenshot, videos, and web.

OS: elementary os 6.1

How can I undo this?

Comment: Can you explain *exactly* what command you issued ? Permissions are for owner, group and other (world). A folder can only be exclusive to root if it is *owned* by root. If it is still owned by you, you can just `chmod 755 name` to get it back. You can't even `chown root name` to *give* it away.

Comment: I do not have access to the terminal

Answer (score -1):

You can change all the file permissions for a directory and all subdirectories and all files in the directory and subdirectories using (as root):

```
chmod -R 777 [directory name]
```

`777` lets each entity do everything.  For more restrictive settings search for the code related to the permissions you wish to give.

Check directory/file ownerships to make sure those didn't get changed somehow.  You can use `chown` command in a similar manner to set those recursively to what you want also.

Comment: It's not advisable to use the root account to manage the system. It's recommended to use `sudo <command>` instead.

Comment: I do not have access to the terminal lol

Comment: I did not use the root account, I used the ‘sudo’ command

Comment: @DirtyDemon97 Using `sudo` without specifying a specific user with `-u` will by default execute the given command _as the root user_ (i.e., you'd be using the root account).

Comment: Oh ok that make sense thanks

Comment: I'm not understanding. You said you have no terminal.  How do you know that the applications folder is only accessible by root. without a terminal?  How do you know whether you are user or root without a terminal?   Any potential helpers need to what what was done to get to this situation.  What desktop are you using?  Are you referring to the Applications in desktop menu or a disk applications directory that has been changed to root?